# Resume last downloaded file upon Exception

Tags: java, exception, amazon-s3, download

I'm using Java SDK 1.11.534

In my tool I declared a download named 'down' using `TransferManager`,

since the call:

```
down.waitForCompletion();
```

is a blocking call and stops the `ProgressBar` acknowledgement by `ProgressListener` I had to introduce a `SwingWorker` as follows:

```
      SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void,Integer>(){


        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            int j = chunks.get(chunks.size()-1);

            if (i<=fileNum) jLabel4.setText("Scaricamento file " + i+ " di " + fileNum + "  del DCP "+ DCPname+" in corso, attendere....");
            else jLabel4.setText("Scaricamento DCP "+ DCPname+" completato con successo.");

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(){

            for (S3ObjectSummary file: fileList){
                  if((!isPresent(destination,file.getKey().substring(file.getKey().lastIndexOf("/") + 1),file.getSize())) && (!(file.getKey().substring(0, file.getKey().length()-1).equals(DCPname)))){

                      publish(i);



             GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, file.getKey());



             down = tx.download(getObjectRequest,new File(percorso+File.separator + file.getKey().substring(file.getKey().lastIndexOf("/") + 1)));

             down.addProgressListener(progressListener);



             try {
                 down.waitForCompletion();
             } catch (AmazonClientException ex) {

                 ex.printStackTrace();
                 tx.shutdownNow(true);
                 //jButton4.setEnabled(true);
                 jButton4.doClick();

             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                 ex.printStackTrace();
                 tx.shutdownNow(true);
                 //jButton4.setEnabled(true);
                 jButton4.doClick();

             }


          i++;  
         }
```

This is a portion of the code where `doInBackground()` shows the operations to do.

It happens sometimes to have an `AmazonClientException` reporting:

> Not all bytes from S3inputstream were read

And this leads to have a corrupted file and a stop of the program itself upon exception.

At the beginning of my code (not reported here) before reaching the `SwingWorker` declaration, I stated that when the `jButton4` is clicked the action starts checking if there's a size mismatch between files in the download folder and the ones on Amazon s3 and if there's a truncated file it gets deleted and the name is added to the download list again.

So the only solution I've found so far is to add the following line code:

```
jButton4.doClick();
```

In the exception code, meaning when an exception is hit the progress restarts and checks for truncated files and restarts downloads adding such a file too.

### My question is:

Is there any way in the SDK to resume or better cancel and then download file again upon exception without restarting the program? I find the usage of:

```
jButton4.doClick();
```

is not a professional way of coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the content of the click action method into a new method and call that method instead.